# fatal error: /usr/include/boost/coroutine/coroutine.hpp: No such file or directory

Tags: compiling, boost

```
fatal error: /usr/include/boost/coroutine/coroutine.hpp: No such file or directory
```

/usr/include/boost can not find coroutine, where is it ?

Answer (score 0):

By default there is no directory named `boost` in `/usr/include`. So, is expected to receive such an error. You can check this with the following command:

```
ls /usr/include/boost
```

It will return:

```
ls: cannot access /usr/include/boost: No such file or directory
```

Comment: how to include coroutine.hpp?